# How can I check existence of the file via C89?

Tags: c

I apologize for my bad English.

Different files can has different permissions. For example I can have not permission for a file read/write, but this file is exists. How can I check existence of the such file via C89?

Thank you. 
Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you stick to C89, there's no universal way of checking for file existence.

There are some standard functions outside of C89, POSIX functions:

[stat()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stat.html)

[fstat()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fstat.html)

At any rate, it depends on the OS since the language itself does not provide such functionality.

Answer (score 3):

In **pure ISO C89, there's no good and portable way of checking the existence of a file.** However, there are implementation-defined solutions or other OS-specific extensions for that. For example:

```
int file_exists(const char *name)
{
     return access(name, F_OK) == 0;
}
```

Note that this (`access()`) is not part of C89, but most systems one cares about have it.

Or there is

```
int file_exists(const char *name)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(name, "r");
    if ((f == NULL) && (errno == ENOENT)) {
        return 0;
    }
    fclose(f);
    return 1;
}
```

This is again not C89, but most C89-conformant systems will provide `ENOENT`.

Another option is to use the `stat()` function, it also returns -1 and sets `errno` to `ENOENT` if the file doesn't exist.

Comment: Where does C89 mention `access` ? In your second function, what happens to the file if the `fopen` succeeds ?

Comment: @cnicutar As I wrote, access is non-standard. I fixed the second one. (To actually answer your second question: if `fopen()` succeeds, the file pointer is being leaked.)

Comment: Then you should fix the wording: *(access()) is listed as implementation-defined in C89* is wrong since it's not listed at all.

Comment: @cnicutar as far as I know, it is listed as implementation-defined in C89. Doesn't that count as nonstandard?

Comment: I can't find it. Point me to the paragraph :-)

Comment: I didn't find `access()` in my ANSI C 89 text file. It's a UNIX/POSIX thing.

Answer (score 2):

There is no portable way to determine wheter a file exists; you have to resort to a system-specific method (such as `access` or `stat` from POSIX.1). Sometimes, it may not be possible to check the existence of a named file, because you don't have permission to read the directory that may contain it.